# How to verify disk space for a given ip WITHOUT a password?

Tags: disk-usage, nagios, plugin

I am writing a Nagios plugin that will check disk space on a given IP (that would be a $HOSTADDRESS$ in plugin). The script is perfectly working but I need to enter a password every time I ssh. I think this is not acceptable in terms of plugin. I wonder, therefore, if there is a way to place a password into a command so plugin will take it automatically?

```
#!/bin/bash

used_space=$(ssh $1 "df -h /" | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 
's/%//g');

case $used_space in
   // here goes OK,WARNING,CRITICAL etc. code
esac
```

Comment: Can `ssh` be configured for key based authentication?

Comment: I realize it's not what you're asking, but this kind of thing is exactly why they invented `nrpe` :) See https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can configure `ssh-keygen` where your plugin  can login to the remote server automatically without a password
2. by `sshpass` in which we can pass the password in the command line itself

   ```
   sshpass -p "password" ssh hostname "df -Ph  | sed -n '/\/$/p'| sed "s/%//g""|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
   ```